# case or if else in a where clause Sql Server

Tags: sql-server-2012, case, where-clause

I using the following query and I am using case statement in where cause with parmeters

when report_type = 'All' then I need all rows and no selection is necessary, however if I select 'AR' or 'BD' I only need those respective statements to be included. However when I tried implement the following logic it is throwing me and error near by OR not sure where I am doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
select * from aging agedet where

( 
 'All' = {?Report_Type} 
 OR 
( 
CASE 
WHEN {?Report_type} = 'AR' THEN 
  (agedet.bkt_type_ha_c <> 5 
  AND 
  agedet.extern_ar_flag_yn <> 'Y' 
  AND 
  agedet.bad_debt_flag_yn <> 'Y') 
  CASE 
  WHEN {?Report_type} = 'Bd' THEN 
    (agedet.bkt_type_ha_c = 5 
    AND 
    agedet.extern_ar_flag_yn = 'Y' 
    AND 
    agedet.bad_debt_flag_yn = 'Y') 
  END ) 
)
```